# Keras LSTM Restore States from Respective Sequences

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a task where training data comes from several long sequences. I want to train with randomly chosen sequence, but not change the order within those sequences (because long term dependencies might be there).

I think this means to choose a sequence number, restore the previous state from that sequence, train, save the new state from that sequence, rinse and repeat.

Is there any way to specify the state when you're training a layer created with keras' LSTM? Do I have to go to my backend? (which is tensorflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1947

I could use `K.set_value(lstm.states[i], val)` or `K.get_value(lstm.states[i])`